# SQL optimization: Four statements into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some columns, one holds a timestamp that I use to run
currently four single selects to compute a `SELECT count()` and return information
like "n-rows older than 1 week", "n-rows older than 2 weeks", ...

How to transform the four queries into one SQL-Statement that is hopefully
running faster?

The statements look like this:

```
SELECT count(foo_pk) AS oneweek FROM foo WHERE foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 week)
```

Comment: The INTERVAL changes to "2 week", "3 week", "4 week".

Comment: From what language are you pulling this data, or is it just in a query editor or something?

Comment: @Elad: It's a SQL statement, here MySQL. The column names are fake, that's all.

Comment: I was thinking maybe if you query the data from C# / php/ whatever - it might be more efficient to get the whole range in one table in one query and filter the results in the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a MySql guy, but in SQL Server I would use the CASE statement like so:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 week) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as oneweek,
    SUM(CASE WHEN foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 week) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as twoweek,
    SUM(CASE WHEN foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 week) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as threeweek,
    SUM(CASE WHEN foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 4 week) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as fourweek
FROM foo
WHERE 
    foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 week)
```

It seems that this statement is available in MySql as well, so while my syntax might be a bit off I think something like the SQL above should work.

Comment: @rsbarro / @martin - Where is my error in reasoning: What is the WHERE clause supposed to do if the first four SUMS/COUNTS count the "older than" rows? Why this exclusion?

Comment: @initall Say you have 10 years worth of data in the table. If you're only looking to get COUNTS for 4 weeks it's better to just exclude all data that you know you don't need to COUNT. The result with or without the WHERE will be the same, but the query with the WHERE clause should return faster.

Comment: @initall - You're right. Didn't read the question properly. Corrected!

Comment: @rsbarro: If there is an index on foo_timestamp, does it really matter?

Comment: @rsbarro: But aren't the only data I can exclude the ones from now() to week 1 if I'm going to start with sum("what's older than 1 week") - a very small portion?

Comment: @ypercube: You could be right, it might not matter. Without having the database to test with, I'm going to have to say 'maybe'. Looking at the query again it might not be necessary, but I wouldn't take it out until I saw the query execution plans with and without.

Comment: @initall Yea, I see what you're saying. The WHERE cause can probably be removed without any ill effects. My initial comment was based on the fact that I thought we were selecting a small subset of data out of this table. Sometimes it's tough when you don't have the actual data to look at. =]

Comment: @rsbarro: On the other hand, I now think it's good to have and leave the final WHERE there. It doesn't hurt and if the conditions inside CASE are altered (and don't use the index any more), the check will become beneficial.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(1) AS olderthanoneweek, 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 week) THEN 1 END) AS olderthantwoweek,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 week) THEN 1 END) AS olderthanthreeweek, 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 4 week) THEN 1 END) AS olderthanfourweek 
FROM foo 
WHERE foo_timstamp < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 week)
```

Comment: @Martin What happens in MySql if no ELSE is supplied in the CASE statement? Does it return NULL and then that result is ignored by COUNT?

Comment: @rsbarro - Yes. There is an implicit `ELSE NULL` and `COUNT` only counts `NOT NULL` values

Comment: @Martin How about that, just tried it out and CASE works the same way in SQL Server, too. Learn something new every day... =] Thanks!

Comment: @Martin I think you want to update the WHERE clause to INTERVAL 4 week.

Comment: @rsbarro - No. The OP is interested in all records at least 1 week old. `DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 week)` gives the date 1 week ago. These records are needed to get the "n-rows older than 1 week" specified in the question.

Comment: @Martin Oh, ok. I see it now. Sorry about that. =]

Comment: @Martin / @rsbarro - Thank you, guys. In a better world I would have been able to give you two the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Untried, but..

```
select count(foo_pk), 
if(foo_timestamp<date_sub(now(),interval 1 week,"in the last week",
if(foo_timestamp<date_sub(now(),interval 2 week,"in the last 2 weeks",
if(foo_timestamp<date_sub(now(),interval 3 week,"in the last 3 weeks",
if(foo_timestamp<date_sub(now(),interval 4 week,"in the last 4 weeks",
                                                "4 weeks or more   ")))) as foo_label
order by foo_label
group by foo_label;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have it in Rows like this, if you like:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL) AS WEEK_DIFF,
  count(foo_pk) AS COUNT_PER_WEEK
FROM foo
GROUP BY DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), 
       round(datediff(curdate(), foo_pk) / 7)
         as week_diff
from wolffinder_experiment
group by week_diff
order by week_diff
having week_diff <= 4
limit 4;
```